# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext(run mnist example with tensorflow on spark)

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, tensorflow

I run a mnist example with tensorflow on spark.

spark:2.1.0

scala:2.11.8

tensorflow:0.12.1

tensorflow on spark: lastest

python: anaconda (python=3.5)

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

the error context:

```
(tf012-p35) superstar@superstar-System-Product-Name:~/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark$ ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit \
>     --master ${MASTER} \
>     --py-files /home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/tfspark.zip,/home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/examples/mnist/spark/mnist_dist.py \
>     --conf spark.cores.max=${TOTAL_CORES} \
>     --conf spark.task.cpus=${CORES_PER_WORKER} \
>     --conf spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME" \
>     /home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/examples/mnist/spark/mnist_spark.py \
>     --cluster_size ${SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES} \
>     --images examples/mnist/csv/train/images \
>     --labels examples/mnist/csv/train/labels \
>     --format csv \
>     --mode train \
>     --model mnist_model

I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/03/17 18:08:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: superstar
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: superstar
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(superstar); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(superstar); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 33685.
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-27ad28b7-ac07-4d51-86fd-1576e429faf0
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 192.168.50.200, and started at http://192.168.50.200:4040
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/examples/mnist/spark/mnist_spark.py at spark://192.168.50.200:33685/files/mnist_spark.py with timestamp 1489745336876
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO Utils: Copying /home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/examples/mnist/spark/mnist_spark.py to /tmp/spark-8e6197a5-5749-4f36-9f80-034986a6a03c/userFiles-71b4732f-9be7-4fb0-9e2a-ccd877ace88d/mnist_spark.py
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/tfspark.zip at spark://192.168.50.200:33685/files/tfspark.zip with timestamp 1489745336881
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO Utils: Copying /home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/tfspark.zip to /tmp/spark-8e6197a5-5749-4f36-9f80-034986a6a03c/userFiles-71b4732f-9be7-4fb0-9e2a-ccd877ace88d/tfspark.zip
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/examples/mnist/spark/mnist_dist.py at spark://192.168.50.200:33685/files/mnist_dist.py with timestamp 1489745336883
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO Utils: Copying /home/superstar/TFSpark/TensorFlowOnSpark/examples/mnist/spark/mnist_dist.py to /tmp/spark-8e6197a5-5749-4f36-9f80-034986a6a03c/userFiles-71b4732f-9be7-4fb0-9e2a-ccd877ace88d/mnist_dist.py
17/03/17 18:08:56 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getInt$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$$anonfun$getInt$2.apply(SparkConf.scala:392)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getInt(SparkConf.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.<init>(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.<init>(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2521)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:501)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/03/17 18:08:56 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.50.200:4040
```

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

I don't know the reason.

The config of spark is wrong? or some software version is not match with others?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think input arguments don't match spark configs check is the order of arguments are correct and valid ?

Comment: Yes. the input argument(TOTAL_CORES/CORES_PER_WORKER/SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES) is empty. So I add them.  Very thanks!

Comment: are u able to echo $JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: JAVA_HOME has added。 The error is input argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think input arguments don't match spark configs check is the order of arguments are correct and valid